# How to set a charset in email using smtplib in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, email, character-encoding, smtplib

I'm writing a simple smtp-sender with authentification. Here's my code

```
    SMTPserver, sender, destination = 'smtp.googlemail.com', 'user@gmail.com', ['reciever@gmail.com']
    USERNAME, PASSWORD = "user", "password"

    # typical values for text_subtype are plain, html, xml
    text_subtype = 'plain'


    content="""
    Hello, world!
    """

    subject="Message Subject"

    from smtplib import SMTP_SSL as SMTP       # this invokes the secure SMTP protocol (port 465, uses SSL)
    # from smtplib import SMTP                  # use this for standard SMTP protocol   (port 25, no encryption)
    from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

    try:
        msg = MIMEText(content, text_subtype)
        msg['Subject']=       subject
        msg['From']   = sender # some SMTP servers will do this automatically, not all

        conn = SMTP(SMTPserver)
        conn.set_debuglevel(False)
        conn.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
        try:
            conn.sendmail(sender, destination, msg.as_string())
        finally:
            conn.close()

    except Exception, exc:
        sys.exit( "mail failed; %s" % str(exc) ) # give a error message
```

It works perfect, untill I try to send non-ascii symbols (russian cyrillic). How should i define a charset in a message to make it show in a proper way? Thanks in advance!

UPD. I've changed my code:

```
text_subtype = 'text'
content="<p>Текст письма</p>"
msg = MIMEText(content, text_subtype)
msg['From']=sender # some SMTP servers will do this automatically, not all
msg['MIME-Version']="1.0"
msg['Subject']="=?UTF-8?Q?Тема письма?="
msg['Content-Type'] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
msg['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = "quoted-printable"
…
conn.sendmail(sender, destination, str(msg))
```

So, first time I spectify text_subtype = 'text', and then in header I place a msg['Content-Type'] = "text/html; charset=utf-8" string. Is it correct?

**UPDATE** Finally, I've solved my message problem
You should write smth like msg = MIMEText(content.encode('utf-8'), 'plain', 'UTF-8')

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
from email.header import Header
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def contains_non_ascii_characters(str):
    return not all(ord(c) < 128 for c in str)   

def add_header(message, header_name, header_value):
    if contains_non_ascii_characters(header_value):
        h = Header(header_value, 'utf-8')
        message[header_name] = h
    else:
        message[header_name] = header_value    
    return message

............
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg = add_header(msg, 'Subject', subject)

if contains_non_ascii_characters(html):
    html_text = MIMEText(html.encode('utf-8'), 'html','utf-8')
else:
    html_text = MIMEText(html, 'html')    

if(contains_non_ascii_characters(plain)):
    plain_text = MIMEText(plain.encode('utf-8'),'plain','utf-8') 
else:
    plain_text = MIMEText(plain,'plain')

msg.attach(plain_text)
msg.attach(html_text)
```

This should give you your proper encoding for both text and headers regardless of whether your text contains non-ASCII characters or not. It also means you won't automatically use base64 encoding unnecessarily.

Comment: Hi Lorcan! How about 'To' and 'From' if I will specify them in my msg (like as msg['From'] = 'my@email.com')? I should to encode it too or not?

Answer (score 5):

You should encode your message-text with UTF-8

```
msg = MIMEText(content.encode('utf-8'), text_subtype).
```

More here:
http://radix.twistedmatrix.com/2010/07/how-to-send-good-unicode-email-with.html

Comment: Shouldn't the encoding also be specified as the third parameter for MIMEText?

Answer (score 2):

You may have to use SMTP header to achieve sending different charsets, try adding this -

`msg['Content-Type'] = "text/html; charset=us-ascii"`

( Change the charset according to your need )

Comment: Well, that worked for me - subject is shown in a proper way, although message text encoding is still incorrecnt.

Comment: I've updated my post. Please, could you take a look at new one