# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 4: unexpected end of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

Im very new to this language and encountered some trouble to send emails through python, my code looks like this:

```
import smtplib
server=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
server.starttls()
server.login('username','password')

message = "hi there"
server.sendmail('username', 'username', message)

server.quit()
```

my system is:
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

and the output I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\pythonfiles\testmail - kopia.py", line 6, in <module>
  server=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
File "C:\python\lib\smtplib.py", line 261, in __init__
  fqdn = socket.getfqdn()
File "C:\python\lib\socket.py", line 676, in getfqdn
  hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in 
position 4: unexpected end of data
```

My computername consists of the letter é can i have to do something with that? Ive saved the file through notepad to UTF-8.

Any ideas?

Cheers André

Comment: Possibly related to Python issue https://bugs.python.org/issue26227 although that is marked as fixed so shouldn't still be occurring on 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

utf-8 is probably not the right encoding.
This is a current problem when parsing files etc including french writting (as I suppose is the case you mention)

I usually solve this problem by :

```
mystring = 'gdjéàếè'
new_string = mystring.encode('iso-8859-1')
```

Otherwise, you may want to check this out: [How to set a charset in email using smtplib in Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295530/how-to-set-a-charset-in-email-using-smtplib-in-python-2-7)

Comment: When i put this code in I recieve
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythonfiles\testmail - kopia.py", line 7, in <module>
    new_string = mystring.encode('iso-8859-1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u1ebf' in position 5: ordinal not in range(256)"

what encoding should i use instead? :)

Comment: This buffles me, usually that is the way to encode é,à,ç etc. The full list of available encodings in python : https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html